# What permissions are needed to develop apps on SPO 365?

Tags: development, configuration, app, office-365

I'm new with SPO365, but from what I read, to deploy and test apps I need a developer site (site collection), but I don't have access to create it, neither access to Central Admin.

Does my developer user needs to be a Farm Admin?

What if SP Administrator creates that site and just add my user to its site collection administrator group, Does this would work?

Comment: you want for SPO or on prem sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ON SPO, Tenant Administrator can create a developer site collection from Office 365 admin center if you have Plan E1 or E3.

You need the Site collection admin rights on developer site collection.

read this for more info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179924(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: From what I read on this link: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manage-administrators-for-a-site-collection-HA102772369.aspx

The SharePoint Online Admin would be the same as the Tenant Administrator that you mention? with that role should be enough right?

Thanks in advance